# Change URL's to friendly-URL using .htaccess file in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change this URL:

```
example.com/movie.php?id=50
```

into

```
example.com/movie/50
```

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error404.php


php_flag display_errors 1


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$    movie.php?id=$1   [NC,L]
```

But it does not work.

Here is what the code does:

If I go to this url:  `example.com/movie/50`

It re-directs me to this URL

```
example.com/movie.php?id=50
```

I just do not want it not to re-direct me (do not change the URL), and open the same content.

Comment: Did you try to proxy it with P instead of L ?

Comment: I Changed it to P now, but same result @SudheeshSinganamalla

Comment: Some other rule must be issuing the 301 redirect. Try placing `DirectorySlash Off` in the .htaccess

Comment: Not working @ishegg

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
function GetURLRewriteArray($url_arr) {
    $url = explode('/', $url_arr);
    unset($url[0]);
    $url = array_values($url);
    $url_array = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($url); $i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $url_array[$url[$i]] = $url[$i + 1];
        }
    }
    return $url_array;
}
print_r(GetURLRewriteArray($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));
```

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G1Jk.png)

Comment: I got this error Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO

Answer (score 0):

first make copy of your htaccess file and try this. i have not tried this but it may work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# if redirected to url cleaner, redirect to actual lookup file and
# these lines will keep the clean url visible in the browser
RewriteRule ^cat_url_cleaner.php ./cat_lookup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^subcat_url_cleaner.php ./subcat_lookup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^subsubcat_url_cleaner.php ./subsubcat_lookup.php [L]

# do not do anything if already existing file, symbolic link or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# redirect clean url (/category) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./cat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./cat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1 [L]

# redirect clean url (/category/subcategory) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$   ./subcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./subcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L]

# redirect clean url (/category/subcategory/subsubcategory) for processing
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./subsubcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2&ss=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./subsubcat_url_cleaner.php?c=$1&s=$2&ss=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Are you answering this question only?